# Simplify natural logarithm when there is a constant

Tags: logarithms

Apologies for lack of latex.

I am trying to simplify `ln(x^2)+1 / ln(x)`

```
ln(x^2) + 1  / ln(x)
= 2 * (ln(x)) + 1 / ln(x)
= 2 + (1 / ln(x))
```

I understand we can get `2 ln(x)` from `ln(x^2)`.  How did we get from step 2 to step 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are parenthesis missing. It should be\begin{align}\frac{\ln(x^2)+1}{\ln x}&=\frac{2\ln(x)+1}{\ln x}\\&=\frac{2\ln x}{\ln x}+\frac1{\ln x}\\&=2+\frac1{\ln x}.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. And how do you type the latex so quickly?

Comment: @GenTan Practice. Maybe even too much practice (I know I am on this site more than I ought to be). I'm even getting quite comfortable writing latex on my mobile, and those keyboards were not meant for anything like that.